# Use CTE in the WHERE clause without JOIN

Tags: sql

I want to search through a list of values in the WHERE clause. The list is in another table and can be returned via CTE. Example:

References table

| ref_number | Other irrelevant columns |
| --- | --- |
| abcdEF | row |
| cdefGH | row |

```
WITH References AS (SELECT ref_number FROM References)
SELECT t.ref,t.* FROM my_tables t
WHERE t.ref IN References
```

This throws an error, I believe IN wants a properly formatted set from the table.

I want to list the references after the IN clause rather than typing them by hand, or otherwise determining the clause to read that condition. I would like the solution for PostgreSQL and for SQL Server if possible. Thank you very much.

Comment: SQL Server <> PostgreSQL; what RDBMS are you *really* using?

Comment: Why do you want to use a CTE here at all though? Your CTE does no kind of transformation so it's completely redundent. It also appears that you think you can reference your CTE like some kind of multi-value scalar value or array; that isn't how CTEs work.

Comment: Maybe I don't need it, can you suggest the correct way?

Comment: `WHERE t.ref IN (SELECT ref_number FROM References)` would be the correct syntax.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I see now. Can you also suggest how to declare it as an array? Or how to declare matrices to check in tuples?

Comment: Depends on your RDBMS on if they support them; we don't know what one you're actually using. Though many don't support arrays; that's a programming concept, SQL isn't a programming language. You deal with data sets and scalar values, not tuples, and work using set based methodology.

Comment: I am using both and I want to learn how to handle this query for both postgresql and sql server

Comment: SQL Server does not support arrays ( cannot speak for PostgreSQL).

Comment: Cut & paste the exact error so that we can see what it says.  If we can't see the error, we can't tell what the problem is.  It's like taking your car to the mechanic and saying "The car makes a noise" but not telling what the noise is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just say "IN CTE", you have to say "IN (select x from CTE)" or simply JOIN the CTE to the rest of the query if appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue. Can you suggest if I should store the set so that it's not always running that subquery? It might benefit from optimisation as the subquery has a lot of values.

Comment: That depends on many factors I can't possibly guess.  That said, the set is already stored in the References table, so there doesn't seem to be any reason to materialize it again just to eliminate the other columns.  And it isn't clear from your simple example why you can't simply join the two tables

Comment: Apologies, in the actual context I don't have the same data in the WHERE clause, although values are overlapping, I am searching for matches with data extracted from a different database. However, it was as simple as you presented, as for multiple criteria I just have to do WHERE (col1=val1 AND col2=val2 AND ...) OR ...

Comment: Might be that the a single value of `ref_number` appears in the table `references` more than once, @Kurt .